# Xilinx error while compiling hello world, missing library - Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: xilinx, ubuntu-14.04, microblaze

I'm am pretty new with `Xilinx`, so it might be a simple problem.

I'm am trying to make a program written in `c`, with the editor `xsdk` for a `microblaze`, I'm am running `Ubuntu 14.04 64 bit`.
When I'm trying to compile the c program i comes with an error:

```
/opt/Xilinx/14.7/ISE_DS/EDK/gnu/microblaze/lin/bin/../lib/gcc/microblaze-xilinx-elf/4.6.4/../../../../microblaze-xilinx-elf/bin/as: 
error while loading shared libraries: libz.so.1: 
cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
make: *** [src/helloworld.o] Error 1
```

The program I'm trying to compile is the standard example hello world, so this should not course any problems.

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like installing the package rpm fixed the problem - honestly i don't know why.